# How to customize border width of ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a default progress bar

[image]

For me it's very large border. How can I make a progress bar like this (with thin border)?

[image]

I have a simple layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hello_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Jsut put android:layout_width and android:layout_height to wrap_content and it'll be perfect for a UI

Comment: I'm posted answer is really help to you please check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a file with shape drawable for your progress

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromDegrees="0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:toDegrees="360">

       <shape
           android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
           android:shape="ring"
           android:thicknessRatio="8"
           android:useLevel="false">

           <solid
                android:color="#F3A523"/>

        </shape>

   </rotate>
   ```
2. Use it inside your `ProgressBar`

   ```
    <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
       android:layout_width="24dp"
       android:layout_height="24dp"
       android:indeterminate="true"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
       android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
     />
   ```

This way you can control width of your border via `thicknessRatio` property of the drawable

Comment: I have default progress bar (which rotating like [this](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html#usage)). How can I extend material progress and apply your solution?

Comment: To start with, if you want 100% material progress bar – you can not change width of it, because that way it's not gonna pass strict material requirements. My solution is a material progress bar. All we have changed is width of border

Comment: It's sad... How can I do infinity rotate this shape?

Comment: @EvgenyNaumov I have updated my answer, take a look. In short – set `indeterminate` to `true` and also set drawable for intermediate state

Comment: this is effective to manipulate the thickness of progressbar but makes a complete circle with no effect of progress like the normal progressbar has

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> 1> Create a Drawable for Ring Progressbar **progressbar.xml** and put
>   into drawabal folder.

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
            <rotate android:toDegrees="360">
                <shape
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="4dp"
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
                    android:thicknessRatio="20.0">
                    <solid android:color="#FF4081" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

> 2> Set above Drawable into your progressbar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/hello_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
             />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Set below properties in drawable file

```
android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
android:thicknessRatio="20.0
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: This solution worked for me, the accepted answer did not animate at all

Answer (score 0):

layout file

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="200"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress" />
```

drawable/progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
       android:shape="ring"
       android:thickness="10dp"
       android:useLevel="true">

      <solid android:color="#05b61c" />
</shape>
```